# Google Sheets Analytics Report Filter For Landing Page Containing number

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

In the Google Sheets Analytics Add-on I'd like to filter landing pages that contain 4 numbers and end with .html . I have used the following command: ga:landingPagePath=@.*[0-9]{4}.html.*$ but it's not working

Comment: What code have you tried so far? What happened and what is the expected response? See [mcve]

Answer (score 0):

Issue solved. I should have used ~= for a regex instead of =@ and ending with .*$ instead of .$; ga:landingPagePath=~.*[0-9]{4}.html.*$